# Microsoft Word "Random" Crashes - possible workaround?

Tags: microsoft-word, crash

Word seemingly randomly crashes in an application setting where it is first being used to programmatically databind (bookmarks) and then directly afterwards opened on the user machine for further user input.

The error message is quite precise but the workaround has eluded me. Word crashes a moment or two after it has been opened on the user machine with the below exception details.

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name: WINWORD.EXE
Application Version: 14.0.6129.5000
Application Timestamp: 5082f354
Fault Module Name: wwlib.dll
Fault Module Version: 14.0.6129.5000
Fault Module Timestamp: 5082f3dc
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset: 000eed32
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.16.7
Locale ID: 1030

Additional information about the problem:
LCID: 1030
skulcid: 1030
```

Sometimes one can run the exact same scenario 50 times before experiencing a crash, other times only a few times. We have tried using different versions of the Word format as well as renaming the databound file after saving so that the file being opened on the user machine is different. Principally Word should never crash but perhaps there is some workaround that can make Word not crash.

Googling for a solution there appears to be multiple things that can trigger this bug.

Edit: So the question is: is there a workaround here?

Comment: -1? Is this an inappropriate question for Superuser?

Comment: Well... It's an issue for MS support IMHO

Comment: I'm actuall battling the same problem right now. Windows XP machine office 2007 fault in wwlib.dll crashes most office products on launch. I've deleted wwlib.dll and I'm just waiting for the repair install of office to finish.

Comment: This sounds like this is exclusive to one computer, so why is the assumption it is a Microsoft bug? Have you ran diagnostics on the hard drive or memory? Have you done a repair install of Office? Have you ran System File Checker? Have you ran a virus/malware scan? All these things are important to know the system integrity is intact before blaming the program as the sole issue.

Comment: @frlan I already tried some suggestions in a Microsoft support forum suggested to a user there with this same error. The user also reported back that they didn't solve the issue.

Comment: @CharlieRB It is not exclusive to one computer - the same problem occors on another computer as well. AND they are specific to some Word templates.

Comment: OK. Then please [edit] your question to include those details. It's important to have all the information when you ask for help.

Comment: Can you describe what is being done to "programmatically bind" bookmarks?